# OMEdit Simulation fails on Mac with dyld error symbol not found

Tags: macos, openmodelica

I am using macports (macOS High Sierra) and openmodelica-devel.
Simulation in OMShell works fine but fails in OMEdit (for any model, compilation works) with the following error:

`dyld: _dyld_bind_fully_image_containing_address() error
dyld: Symbol not found: _dgbtrf
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/x86_64-darwin17.5.0/omc/libsundials_idas.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /opt/local/lib/x86_64-darwin17.5.0/omc/libsundials_idas.0.dylib`

Can anyone help please? I would really like to use OMEdit.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your question at https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/